# Why make high poly mesh and low poly mesh of a same character, and how to use visuals of high poly mesh and performance of a low poly mesh?

Tags: mesh

Hey so after watching several tutorials about retopology, I still don't understand, why make a low poly mesh of a character to animate if I want to animate mesh with higher resolution?

Comment: If you've completed rigging multiple high poly Models in and add an environment you'll sooner or later notice that Blender can't handle all of it smoothly. So i's good to have a low poly Mesh only visible in the Viewport and a high poly only visible in your Render. Just attach them to the same Armature and toggle the visibilty in your Scene Collection.

Comment: How can I attach armature form high poly mesh to low one?

Comment: You can have multiple Objects sharing the same Armature. So even after you've finished rigging one, you can just select a different Object, then select your Armature and press CTRL + P